# HTMLPurifier Not working?

Tags: php, xss, security, htmlpurifier

I'm putting HTMLPurifier through some tests to make sure that everything works as expected. I'm using examples from http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html.  I think everything I coded is 'correct' but I am able to pass one of the xxs examples right through. Can anybody assist me?

Here is the page common1.php it declares a function and processes the data:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

// configuration goes here:
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8'); // replace with your encoding
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Strict'); // replace with your doctype

function purify($data){
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    // untrusted input HTML
    $pure_html = htmlspecialchars($purifier->purify($data));

    return $data;
 }
?>
```

And here is my debug script that attempts (and succeeds 0_o) in passing xxs:

```
<?php
    include('common1.php');

    $t = "<IMG \"\"\"><SCRIPT>alert(\"XSS\")</SCRIPT>\">";
    echo purify($t);
?>
```

Comment: I changed the function name (as well as the function call) to purif88 just to make sure that the title of the function wasn't interfereing with the ->purify().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning the unpurified markup.  Change your return statement:

```
 function purify($data){
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    // untrusted input HTML
    $pure_html = htmlspecialchars($purifier->purify($data));

    return $pure_html;
 }
```

Comment: :smacks head: sorry about that, I totally missed it.